# SAS: Adding "uniform" option to gplot creates weird x-axis values for an integer variable

Tags: statistics, sas

I want to create a set of plots of the mean value of $Y$ against $c$ by $K$. $c$ in this case always takes an integer value of $2$ to $15$.

I use this code to create the plots, using the "uniform" option because I want to keep the y-axis the same.

```
proc means noprint data=two;
 var Y;
 class   K c;
 output out = nn mean=Y; 
run;

 proc sort data= nn; by   K ; run;

 proc gplot data =nn uniform;
 plot Y*c  ;
 symbol interpol=join;
 by  K ;
 run;
```

The output is fine, except that the tick marks on the x-axis for variable $c$ are really weird (image below).

[image]

If I remove the "uniform" option, the x-axis is labeled with integer tick marks, as expected.  Why is this happening?  And, how can I get the y-axis to be uniform across plots, while keeping integer values on the x-axis.

Any thoughts would be very appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define [AXIS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/63022/HTML/default/viewer.htm#axischap.htm) option before plotting. You can carefully customize your plot's axis using this option. For your problem, you wanna create ticker from 2 to 15 with 1 every step, then specify:

```
  AXIS1 label=("c") order=(2 to 15 by 1);
```

at last, add options in gplot statement to force using AXIS1

```
  plot Y*c /haxis=axis1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it!  But, still curious why the behavior is there in the first place.

Comment: @Jand, I never try UNIFORM but What I think is, [uniform](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/63022/HTML/default/viewer.htm#gplot-stmt.htm) specifies only the same value range across plots but not same tickers. It will force scaling axes so could be the reason you got the mess since the value range of Y may be different across K.